# Remove my full name from startup screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, user-account, privacy

Whenever I open the computer the login screen shows up with my account picture and full name. Is there any way to remove it or replace it with the account name or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the *Full Name* for a given user account. From [Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548):

> - Go to Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups.
> - If the lock icon in the corner of the window is locked, click the icon to unlock it. Enter the admin name and password, if prompted.
> - From the list of users, open a shortcut menu by <kbd>Control</kbd>+clicking the user that you want to rename. Choose "Advanced Options" from the
>     shortcut menu.
> - Change the name in the "Full name" field, then click OK.

Changing the *Full Name* here will change the name shown on the login screen you described. **DO NOT** change the short name (or anything else for that matter). Read the warning if you are tempted to change anything other than the *Full Name*:

[image: Warning from the Advanced Options]

Given this warning I would highly recommend making a backup before performing any changes.

I can confirm that updating the *Full Name* (and nothing else) here will not prevent you from logging in. **However, there is always the chance that this will have other unintended consequences**. If needed, you could take these steps again to revert back to the accounts original *Full Name*.

Comment: since OSX 14.0 Sonoma it's possible to hide full name and photo from lock screen in system settings. See my answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464704/320251

Answer (score 1):

You can change under System Preferences → User & Groups → Login options.

[image]

If you select `Name and password`, the login window will appear as usual, but there will no longer be a list of users and accounts shown, instead a basic prompt for a complete username and password is necessary to login to the Mac.

Comment: So I cant have list of Users without full names?

Comment: Nop, just a couple of text boxes to enter username and password.

Comment: But event that doesnt really change it. I still see my full name. It only changes it for the login screen that shows up after you log out

Answer (score 1):

Since OSX 14.0 Sonoma it's possible to hide full name and picture in System Settings -> Lock Screen -> Show user name and photo

[image: Lock screen settings]

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this [Apple Support page](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548) you will find the steps you must take to change the full name.

On Yosemite, opening the user profile while holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key and then selecting Advanced Options leads you to this screen.

Change **only** the Full name field:

[image]

Comment: But I don't see any shortcut menu or Advanced settings there. Could it be because the account is linked to an apple ID ?